# Batch convert a folder of .mkv files to .m4v files using ffmpeg in MAC OS X

Tags: macos, mac, video, ffmpeg, batch

Is there a way to batch covert a folder of .mkv files to .m4v files using ffmpeg in Mac?

I setup a service that will do individual files, but I really would like to batch them.

The 'Run Shell Script' that I'm using is:

```
for f in "$@"
do
    /Users/username/Movies/ffmpeg -i "$f" -c:v copy -c:a copy "${f%.*}.m4v"
done
```

Here is a screen shot of what I have that works for individual files:

[image]

Answer (score 14):

[@ldiastx, please take a look:](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/123657/convert-a-bunch-of-mkv-files-to-mp4-to-read-them-in-itunes)

```
for f in *.mkv;do ffmpeg -i "$f" -c:v copy -c:a aac -b:a 256k "${f%mkv}mp4";done
```

Or if you don't need to re-encode:

```
for f in *.mkv;do ffmpeg -i "$f" -c copy "${f%mkv}mp4";done
```

If you want to put the new files in a separate directory:

```
mkdir output
for f in *.mkv;do ffmpeg -i "$f" -c:v copy -c:a aac -b:a 256k "output/${f%mkv}mp4";done
```

Comment: Dude:  I am struggling with this a bit. The name of my files are this format....

tvshow s01e01 - name of tvshow.mkv

my script still will do individual files within the folder. I just right click the file and look under services and then select the name of my service that i created.

If I try right clicking on my folder name. I get an error.

Comment: Just try running Dude's command inside Terminal!  It should loop thru all the MKV files in the current folder/directory, converting them to MP4.  It preserves the names of the files, just changing the extension.

Comment: PERFECT!  Thanks so much. Works like a charm.

Comment: Curious what "${f%mkv}mp4" is? Learn more about "String Operations": http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/refcards.html#AEN22828

Answer (score 1):

For **fish** shell:

```
for f in *.mkv
   set fnew (string replace .mkv .mp4 $f)
   ffmpeg -i $f -c copy $fnew
end
```